# Python multiprocessing question on iteration of a function multiple arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need some help on this, I have played around with multiple options on stackoverflow and internet. But I need some help on this as I'm confused. I'm on Python 2.7.

This is my manager for the multi-processing. I just need to iterate function1 based on the n_iterations and collect the result per each iteration. 
I have imported the two libraries,

```
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing
```

Function1 is;

```
def function1(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5):
    calculate_function = v1+v2+v3+v4+v5
    return calculate_function
```

And the function to handle the multi-processing is,

```
def multi_process(n_iterations,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5):
    sampling_process = partial(function1, v1=a1,v2=a2,v3=a3,v4=a4,v5=a5)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results_set = pool.map(sampling_process, xrange(n_iterations)) 
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results_set
```

But I keep getting an error message,

```
  File "model_selection_pooling_ray.py", line 246, in multi_process
    results_set = pool.map(sampling_process, xrange(n_iterations)) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: global name 'valuofv1' is not defined
```

(valuofv1 is the actual value on a1)
Can someone please help me out on figuring out what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the sampling_process does not need any args, you can define the Function1:

```
def function1(n, v1,v2,v3,v4,v5):
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, would you be able to elaborate it bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the problem was related to the actual code calling for the function `valueof1` which did not exist. After fixing this, I adjusted function1 to include the iterating value as well, `def function1(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,n):` to fix it.